# Trim last 3 characters of a line WITHOUT using sed, or perl, etc

Tags: unix, shell, sed

I've got a shell script outputting data like this:

```
1234567890  *
1234567891  *
```

I need to remove JUST the last three characters "  *". I know I can do it via

```
(whatever) | sed 's/\(.*\).../\1/'
```

But I DON'T want to use sed for speed purposes. It will always be the same last 3 characters.

Any quick way of cleaning up the output?

Comment: @RubiCon, you're starting your question with an incorrect assumption (that `sed` will slow you down).

Comment: pax - i believe that regular expressions take longer than simple  operations on character strings. I dont think I'm wrong, but feel free to show otherwise...

Comment: Ah, a challenge. I _love_ challenges :-) See my update. Short answer. Complex REs (with lookaheads and trackbacks and all that sort of stuff) are slower than dedicated code. But yours is _not_ a complex RE. The compiled parser will be pretty fast even compared to dedicated code. Certainly the time difference will not be relevant for something happening once an hour (whether it takes 0.4 seconds or 0.8 seconds should not be a concern).

Comment: Can you say anything else about the data?  (e.g. will it always be 13 characters per line?)  Also what platform will you be using?

Comment: @RubiCon10 it's kind of hard to accept your assertion that sed will somehow not be fast enough ... you've already stated that the output is coming from a shell script.  It's virtually impossible for sed to be the bottleneck in such a pipeline!  In other words, if speed is such a concern then you might get more benefit from focusing on the rest of your code.

Comment: Agreeing 100% with Zac, besides, the only way a regex can slow you down here is if you're using a POSIX NFA engine or a regular NFA engine and you have no match. awk which uses a DFA with a good regex will not slow you down.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming all data is formatted like your example, use '[cut](http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/cut.shtml)' to get the first column only.

```
cat $file | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

or to get the first 10 chars.

```
cat $file | cut -c 1-10
```

Comment: @Zac: You're right. I saw that his answer looked clunky, but didn't read the comment underneath. He didn't mention selecting only the first 10 chars per line though.

Comment: Useless use of cat. Save a process today and run `cut -c 1-10 $file`.

Comment: Still slower than sed on mine.

Answer (score 199):

Here's an old-fashioned unix trick for removing the last 3 characters from a line that
makes no use of sed OR awk...

```
> echo 987654321 | rev | cut -c 4- | rev

987654
```

Unlike the earlier example using 'cut', this does not require knowledge of the line length.

Comment: If I could, I'd buy you beer and send it your way.

Comment: Technically, the request was for an answer without `sed`, `perl` or ***etc.*** I took that to mean *any* external tool.

Comment: OK this is pure genius

Comment: old school as hell

Comment: **Technical explanation:** Cut by character only words at the beginning of strings so we reverses the string (_hello bai_ **->** _iab olleh_), cut the beginning, then reverse again bringing the string back to it's proper order.

Comment: This also lets you do multi-byte-aware character truncation (vs. bytes) from the end using cut -c, versus head/tail which only work on bytes.

Answer (score 33):

I can guarantee you that `bash` alone won't be any faster than `sed` for this task.  Starting up external processes in `bash` is a generally bad idea but only if you do it a lot.

So, if you're starting a `sed` process for *each* line of your input, I'd be concerned. But you're not. You only need to start *one* `sed` which will do all the work for you.

You may however find that the following `sed` will be a bit faster than your version:

```
(whatever) | sed 's/...$//'
```

All this does is remove the last three characters on each line, rather than substituting the whole line with a shorter version of itself. Now maybe more modern RE engines can optimise your command but why take the risk.

To be honest, about the only way I can think of that would be faster would be to hand-craft your own C-based filter program. And the only reason that *may* be faster than `sed` is because you can take advantage of the extra knowledge you have on your processing needs (`sed` has to allow for generalised procession so may be slower because of that).

Don't forget the optimisation mantra: *"Measure, don't guess!"*

---

If you *really* want to do this one line at a time in `bash` (and I still maintain that it's a bad idea), you can use:

```
pax> line=123456789abc
pax> line2=${line%%???}
pax> echo ${line2}
123456789
pax> _
```

---

You may also want to investigate whether you actually *need* a speed improvement. If you process the lines as one big chunk, you'll see that `sed` is plenty fast. Type in the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

echo This is a pretty chunky line with three bad characters at the end.XXX >qq1
for i in 4 16 64 256 1024 4096 16384 65536 ; do
    cat qq1 qq1 >qq2
    cat qq2 qq2 >qq1
done

head -20000l qq1 >qq2
wc -l qq2

date
time sed 's/...$//' qq2 >qq1
date
head -3l qq1
```

and run it. Here's the output on my (not very fast at all) R40 laptop:

```
pax> ./chk.sh
20000 qq2
Sat Jul 24 13:09:15 WAST 2010

real    0m0.851s
user    0m0.781s
sys     0m0.050s
Sat Jul 24 13:09:16 WAST 2010
This is a pretty chunky line with three bad characters at the end.
This is a pretty chunky line with three bad characters at the end.
This is a pretty chunky line with three bad characters at the end.
```

That's 20,000 lines in under a second, pretty good for something that's only done every hour.

Comment: ... actually yes, this is for every line of input say ~200 lines in one case and ~20000 in another... run every 5 mins and 60 mins for the second...

Comment: _Why_ are you doing it for every line? If you want to process 200/20K lines, do it once (with one `sed`). That `sed` command will breeze through 20K lines in under a second on my crappy old IBM ThinkPad R40.

Comment: Wow! Nice script! `for i in {1..20000}; do echo "line of text...XXX"; done | time -p sed 's/...$//' >/dev/null` - eliminating  `cat` and `head` and at least one file. Even if you added back in some of the diagnostic output, "for i in 4 16 64 256 1024 4096 16384 65536" *really*? This is the same: `for i in x x x x x x x x`

Comment: I really don't know why people concentrate on throwaway parts of scripts. The bit being questioned is DEBUG code for setting up test data solely for measuring the speed at the request of the OP, and it doesn't matter one bit whether it's done one way or another. The important bit is the _single line containing the_ `sed` _command!_

Comment: Hi pax - thanks for your input - I did rework the code to generate all the lines at once... and then did speed measurements as you suggested!! And I found that the cut -d statement was faster than sed in this case (it took half the time).

Comment: I should add that although Larry's answer is the one i ended up using, its your suggestion of actual measurement that made me reworkd the code and save quite a bit of time this method! So - thank you! :)

Comment: No problems, @RubiCon10, I still got 50 rep out of it :-) If the other answer is better (faster in your particular case), then you _should_ accept it.

Answer (score 14):

```
$ x="can_haz"
$ echo "${x%???}"
can_
```

Comment: This answer is super simple. Unless it is slower than cut, sed, etc., it seems best to me.

Comment: Question: What is the difference between using one '%' and two '%%' ?, what is '%' and '?' for?

Answer (score 5):

Both `awk` and `sed` are plenty fast, but if you think it matters feel free to use one of the following:

**If the characters that you want to delete are always at the end of the string**

```
echo '1234567890  *' | tr -d ' *'
```

**If they can appear anywhere within the string and you only want to delete those at the end**

```
echo '1234567890  *' | rev | cut -c 4- | rev
```

The man pages of all the commands will explain what's going on.

I think you should use `sed`, though.

Comment: Hi majhool - see comment above to paxdiablo - will tr be faster or the rev/cut/rev combination?

Comment: tr.  You could also use the venerable cut -d ' ' -f 1 if the tr line will work for you.  Though again, I'd recommend sed, since this will break if you end up with more spaces than you expect.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** This answer is somewhat intended to be a joke, but it actually does work...

```
#!/bin/bash
outfile="/tmp/$RANDOM"
cfile="$outfile.c"
echo '#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){int e=1;char c;while((c=getc(stdin))!=-1){if(c==10)e=1;if(c==32)e=0;if(e)putc(c,stdout);}}' >> "$cfile"
gcc -o "$outfile" "$cfile"
rm "$cfile"
cat somedata.txt | "$outfile"
rm "$outfile"
```

You can replace `cat somedata.txt` with a different command.

Comment: This actually would be quite fast if it didn't compile it each time, I believe.

Comment: Replace `gcc` with `tcc` (tinyc) and I'm pretty sure the 'compiling' overhead will be trivial. Especially if you never write a binary but have `tcc` run it immediately.

Comment: How about a script that uploads your text to a webserver, then downloads it again using HTTP's `Range: bytes=0-...` header. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
(whatever) | while read line; do echo $line | head --bytes -3; done;
```

`head` itself should be faster than `sed` or `cut` because there's no regex or delimeter matching, but invoking a for every line separately would probably outweigh that.

Answer (score 1):

If the script always outputs lines of 10 characters followed by 3 extra (in other words, you just want the first 10 characters), you can use

```
script | cut -c 1-10
```

If it outputs an uncertain number of non-space characters, followed by a space and then 2 other extra characters (in other words, you just want the first field), you can use

```
script | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

... as in majhool's comment earlier.  Depending on your platform, you may also have colrm, which, again, would work if the lines are a fixed length:

```
script | colrm 11
```

Answer (score 1):

Another answer relies on the third-to-last character being a space. This will work with (almost) any character in that position and does it "WITHOUT using sed, or perl, etc.":

```
while read -r line
do
    echo ${line:0:${#line}-3}
done
```

If your lines are fixed length change the `echo` to:

```
echo ${line:0:9}
```

or

```
printf "%.10s\n" "$line"
```

but each of these is *definitely* ***much*** slower than `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

No need for cut or magic, in bash you can cut a string like so:

```
  ORGSTRING="123456"
  CUTSTRING=${ORGSTRING:0:-3}
  echo "The original string: $ORGSTRING"
  echo "The new, shorter and faster string: $CUTSTRING"
```

See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk just to print the first 'field' if there won't be any spaces (or if there will be, change the separator'.

I put the fields you had above into a file and did this

```
awk '{ print $1 }' < test.txt 
1234567890
1234567891
```

I don't know if that's any better.

Comment: Thanks sdeer - but dont want to use awk either... _really_ need the speed on this one...

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean don't want to use sed/awk for speed purposes? sed/awk are faster than the shell's while read loop for processing files.

```
$ sed 's/[ \t]*\*$//' file
1234567890
1234567891

$ sed 's/..\*$//' file
1234567890
1234567891
```

with bash shell

```
while read -r a b
do
 echo $a
done <file
```